# How can I know which radio button is selected in php?

Tags: php, html

This is my radio form in html:

```
<form action="form2.php" method="POST">
<label><input type="radio" name="select" value="insert"> Insert </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="select" value="remove"> Remove </label>
</form>
```

How can I check which of 2 radio is chosen in php file (connected with database).
For example, if is selected insert then add new member. If selected remove then remove a member.

```
$select = $_REQUEST['select'];
echo $select;
```

It returns "on" not insert/Insert nor remove/Remove

Comment: Add a `value` attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: fyi, you can remove `</select>`

Comment: thanks to correct my imprecision but the problem is not solved yet :(

Comment: Then you did something wrong. This is the way to go. If you submit the code you posted `$_REQUEST['select']` will either be `insert` or `remove` - depending on which radio you checked. How do you submit the form, since there is no submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `value` attribute to your radio inputs:

```
<form action="form2.php" method="POST">
<label><input type="radio" name="select" value="insert"> Insert</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="select" value="remove"> Remove</label>
<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

I also added a submit button.

If `form2.php` contains

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST['select'];
```

or

```
<?php
echo $_POST['select'];
```

it will print out `insert` or `remove` after you submit the form
depending on which radio you selected.

More on radio inputs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. Just check the value of your post data.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['select'])){
  switch ($_REQUEST['select']) {
      case 'insert':
        // Insert new

        break;
      
      case 'remove':
        // Remove
        break;
    }  
}
```